# What set do the following concepts belong to?

Tags: geometry

I am a computer science masters degree holder. Recently I have started studying Computer Vision. While reading the book by Szeliski, I am struggling a lot with the geometric concepts. For example things like projective geometry, quaternion, exponential twist etc.

My question is - do these concept belong to one area or branch of geometry (which I must have not taken)? I am not new to vector geometry in general. For example I know what cross product mean and can find my way through 3D geometry derivations. But most of the statements in this computer vision book is just given without much intuition.

Is there a text book that covers these topics? For those who are by now eager to vote to close this question as subjective (not objective) - Consider a formal question like this (which can't be subjective) : what is/are the set of major concepts in geometry that are widely used in Computer Vision? And what is minimal set of names for these collection of concepts (roundabout way of asking what text book covers them or what would be possible names of these books)?

Comment: The following may help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824679/how-can-i-learn-the-math-necessary-for-working-with-computer-vision

Comment: I read it. It says things like calculus and linear algebra. These are not my problems though. I am struggling with geometric statements like cross product of homogeneous line denotes their intersection. It took me 3 days to get it. In the book I was reading it just mentioned it like an obvious fact. So I am having issue with the geometry part. But I liked the idea of looking at the preface. I will do it. And I will also contact the writer if needed. Thanks.